# Recording last meeting date on object

Tags: event

I am recording meetings (events) against my contact records, and I would like to have a field on my contact record that shows the date of the last meeting, and one that shows the date of the next meeting.

Is it possible to do this without coding?
Tia.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile so apologies for typos and/or brevity.

One possibility to try that avoids code (havent tried it myself) would be to use the inline charting capability, and use reporting to present a snapshot of meeting data on a contact page when you open it, including the info you want as well as a paint a picture of #meetings over time for example. Or, if dont want chart use a metric component for each of next meeting and last meeting. Doubt it'd be pretty but may achieve the outcome you need until can code it more elegantly.